# Gulp.js : unexpected token (23:12) while parsing

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm tryin to use gulp.js in my project and I confronted some problems like this :

```
[08:57:25] { [SyntaxError: Unexpected token (23:12) while parsing c:\Users\user\
desktop\responsive\components\scripts\fake_b1eb0d8e.js]
  plugin: 'gulp-browserify',
  showStack: false,
  name: 'SyntaxError',
  message: 'Unexpected token (23:12) while parsing c:\\Users\\user\\desktop\\res
ponsive\\components\\scripts\\fake_b1eb0d8e.js',
  fileName: undefined,
  lineNumber: undefined,
  stack: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token (23:12) while parsing c:\\Users\\user\\d
esktop\\responsive\\components\\scripts\\fake_b1eb0d8e.js\n    at Stream.end (c:
\\Users\\user\\desktop\\responsive\\node_modules\\gulp-browserify\\node_modules\
\browserify\\node_modules\\insert-module-globals\\index.js:71:21)\n    at _end (
c:\\Users\\user\\desktop\\responsive\\node_modules\\gulp-browserify\\node_module
s\\browserify\\node_modules\\insert-module-globals\\node_modules\\through\\index
.js:65:9)\n    at Stream.stream.end (c:\\Users\\user\\desktop\\responsive\\node_
modules\\gulp-browserify\\node_modules\\browserify\\node_modules\\insert-module-
globals\\node_modules\\through\\index.js:74:5)\n    at Transform.onend (c:\\User
s\\user\\desktop\\responsive\\node_modules\\gulp-browserify\\node_modules\\throu
gh2\\node_modules\\readable-stream\\lib\\_stream_readable.js:523:10)\n    at Tra
nsform.g (events.js:199:16)\n    at Transform.emit (events.js:129:20)\n    at c:
\\Users\\user\\desktop\\responsive\\node_modules\\gulp-browserify\\node_modules\
\through2\\node_modules\\readable-stream\\lib\\_stream_readable.js:965:16\n    a
t process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)' }
```

Comment: Error points to a `.js` file and you have tagged `sass`. Could you open up a little and share that `fake_xxx.js` with us somewhere around that L:23?

Comment: i search in my directory : c:\\Users\\user\\d
esktop\\responsive\\components\\scripts\\fake_b1eb0d8e.js    and i havn't this file : fake_b1eb0d8e.js

Comment: this is a image in my Git Bash : [link](http://i59.tinypic.com/ap9xjs.png)  Please Help Me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem initially, before I realised that the problem was based on a smooth scrolling code snippet from css-tricks.com, specifically the first line of code

`a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function()`

Now, this selector is not valid. # is a special char and needs to be escaped like `a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])`

see https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Hope it can help someone somewhere